# Decoupled application with SAML authentication

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, express, saml

we have a requirement to implement authentication via SAML.
The frontend is implemented in Angular. The backend is a REST API implemented in node express. Frontend and backend are running decoupled at the moment (which was also requirement).

In the examples of SAML implementations that exist on the web, frontend and backend usually run coupled. In general: Is it possible to implement authentication via SAML when frontend and backend are decoupled?

Here is a short summary of our findings so far and the corresponding difficulties:

- At login, a redirect to a login mask of the identity provider (in our case AD FS) is performed. So, as we understand it, this action must be performed in the frontend.
- A callback via POST must be provided for the identity provider to receive information after authentication. This callback can only be implemented in the backend because the Angular app cannot accept a POST request.

Is it possible to reconcile this? And if yes, how?
In the sample implementations, the Angular app is often served through the node server. Is this a basic precondition for implementing SAML?

Perhaps someone knows of a sample implementation where the frontend and backend are running separately or can provide a brief note on the division of responsibilities to implement authentication in this setup.

Comment: Please refer to this is stackoverflow article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65250156/saml-authentication-using-angular-node-js-and-an-identity-provider

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not sure, if this is a good solution.
1. I guess we should use the Login Page of identity provider instead of passing username and password through our backend.
2. If I get SAML right, the token would come to us through our provided callback. Should we keep the connection to the client open until we received the callback?
Sounds a bit strange overall and as if SAML was not intended for this use case.

Comment: SAML protocol is not designated for SPA, but for server applications, so you really need weird, backend coupled solution. Or drop requirement for SAML SSO protocol and use OIDC SSO protocol (anyway, good IDP implementations support both SSO protocols, so apps can choose the better SSO protol for them without loosing SSO functionality).